# Carregar ViewModel e template externo para o componente Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs

**Estou tentando carregar o template e a ViewModel para um componente knockout usando require.js, mas até agora sem êxito.**

**index.html (view)**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-main="assets/js/app" src="assets/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table_n></table_n>
</body>
```

**menu.html (Template)**

```
<table class="table table- bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align=center width=60 style="display: none">Código</th>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Ordem</th>
            <th>Imagem url</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: ListaUsuarios()}">
        <tr>
            <td style="display: none" data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: titulo"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: descricao"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ordem"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: caminho_imagem"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**menu.js (ViewModel)**

```
define(['knockout', 'knockoutMapping'], function (ko, komap) {
    debugger;
    var self = this;
    debugger;
    self.filter = ko.observable('');
    self.ListaUsuarios = ko.observableArray();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.15.3/api/menus",
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var a = JSON.stringify(result);
            var observableData = komap.fromJS(result);
            var array = observableData();
            self.ListaUsuarios(array);
        }
     });
});
```

**App.js (inicializando os parametros no knockout)**

```
(function (undefined) {
    'use strict';
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: './', // Raiz
        urlArgs: function (id, url) {
            return (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'v=23';
        }, // Debug Cache
        deps: ['assets/js/base'],
        map: {
            '*': {
                'jQuery': 'jquery'
            }
        },
        paths: {
            // Módulos
            'jquery': 'assets/js/vendor/jquery-3.1.1',
            // Library jQuery
            'knockout': 'assets/js/vendor/knockout-3.4.2',
            'knockoutMapping': 'assets/js/vendor/knockout.mapping-latest',
            // Config
            'start': 'assets/js/start'
        },
        shim: {
            'knockoutMapping': {
                deps: ['knockout']
            }
        },
        waitSeconds: 15
    });
    // Chamando módulo principal para iniciar a aplicação
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        require(['start']);
    });
    requirejs.onError = function (err) {
        console.log(err.requireType);
        console.log('modules: ' + err.requireModules);
        throw err;
    };
}());
```

**base.js (Usando jQuery como um módulo chamado em RequireJS)**

```
(function () {
    define(['jquery'], function () {
        (function ($) {
            console.info('Verificando Global jQuery...');
            if (typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.document === 'object') {
                if (!!window && !(!!window.$)) {
                    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
                }
                console.log([$, jQuery]);
            }
            var version = $().jquery;
            if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery) {
                console.info('jQuery: ' + version + ' $.fn.jquery: ' + $.fn.jquery);
                return window.jQuery;
            }
        }(jQuery));
    });
}());
```

**start.js (e finalmente inicializando o componente)**

```
define(['knockout', 'knockoutMapping'], function (ko, komap) {
    debugger;
    ko.components.register('table_n', {
        viewModel: { require: 'assets/js/component/viewmodel/menu' },
        template: { require: 'text!assets/js/component/templates/menu.html' }
    });

    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

**E abaixo os tristes erros!**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de ver alguns exemplos sobre o uso do require.js, eu entendi o que estava fazendo de errado:

Os arquivos index.html, menu.html(template) estão corretos, mas no menu.js (ViewModel) eu mudei a primeira linha para incluir a ** biblioteca Jquery ** e ficou assim:

```
Define (['jquery', 'knockout', 'knockoutMapping'], função ($, ko, komap) {
```

E no final do arquivo depois:

```
Self.User List (array);
```

Eu adicionei o Knockout Applybinds:

```
Ko.applyBindings ();
```

Antes o applybindings estava no arquivo start.js, no entanto, como eu estou consultando um WebApi com ajax (que é assíncrono), ele era ativado antes de o ajax receber a resposta e isso causava um dos erros.

No arquivo app.js adicionei uma **bibliteca em javascript** chamada text.js na session Paths, esta biblioteca pode ser encontrada em [baixar aqui](https://github.com/requirejs/text). Ela é
necessária para carregar o template, porque o require.js por padrão carrega apenas arquivos javascript, isso gerava outro erro.

E também adicionei o caminho para o menu viewmodel.js
A parte modificada do arquivo foi assim

```
  'Texto': 'assets/js/vendor/text',
  'Menu': 'assets/js/component/viewmodel/menu',
```

Lembre-se de que isso deve ser adicionado na session Paths depois de 'knockoutMapping' e antes do 'start'.

O arquivo base.js também não foi alterado.

E no arquivo start.js foi removido, como eu disse anteriormente, o applybindings e também modificada a primeira linha. Agora eu chamei o Viewmodel e o modelo pelas variáveis ​​que foram referenciadas no 'define'. E o arquivo ficou assim:

** Start.js: **

```
Define (['knockout', 'knockoutMapping', 'menu', 'text!Assets/js/component/ templates/menu.html'], função (ko, komap, menu, menuhtml) {
    Ko.components.register ('table_n', {
        ViewModel: menu,
        Modelo: menuhtml
    });
});
```

E com isso a tabela foi carregada corretamente.